# Why am i getting an error SyntaxError : invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a python code for which i am getting an error...

```
    from scipy import *
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    x=arange(0.1,100,0.1)
    f=zeros(len(x))
    s=-1
    for n in range (1,10000):
        t=s*x/(x*x+n*n)
        f +=t
        s =-s
        if max(abs(t))< 1e-4
            break
    for xx in c_[x,f]:
        print "%f    %f" % (xx[0],xx[1])
```

Comment: I think, [so] site is better for this kind of questions

Answer (score 3):

Your parens in the equation for `z` are unbalanced.